# Upgrading continuity of measures

Tags: measure-theory

I wonder if continuity of measures holds more generally. In particular, if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is any collection of measurable sets, linearly ordered by inclusion--that is, if $E,F\in{\cal E}$, then either $E\subseteq F$ or $F\subseteq E$--, then is it true that $\bigcup_{E\in{\cal E}}$ is measurable and

$$ \mu\Big(\bigcup_{E\in{\cal E}}C\Big)=\sup_{E\in{\cal E}} \mu(E) $$

in analogy to $\mu(\bigcup_n E_n)=\sup_n \mu(E_n)$ for countable collections?

Comment: what exactly does linearly ordered by inclusion mean? Also, if the collection is arbitrary, the quantity on the left need not be well-defined, though I suppose you can always take outer measure

Comment: Valid questions! Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample (assuming the Continuum Hypothesis).  This example goes back to Ulam.

Let $\omega_1$ be the set of all countable ordinals.  There is a bijection $\phi : \omega_1 \to \mathbb [0,1]$ according to CH.  Next note that the family of "initial interval" sets
$$
[0,\alpha) := \big\{\gamma \in \omega_1\,:\,0\le \gamma < \alpha\big\}, \quad\text{where } \alpha \in \omega_1 ,
$$
is a family of countable subsets of $\omega_1$, linearly ordered by inclusion, with union $\omega_1$ itself.  Then
$$
E_\alpha = \phi\big([0,\alpha)\big) ,\quad\text{where } \alpha \in \omega_1 ,
$$
is a family of countable subsets of $[0,1]$, linearly ordered by inclusion, with union $[0,1]$.  Of course for $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, we have
$\mu(E_\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha$, but $\mu(\bigcup_\alpha E_\alpha) = 1$.

---

Comment: Fun! Thanks for the example!